# Window.open() in ext Js

Tags: jsp, extjs, onclicklistener

I have to load a new jsp page in the on click event of a button in ext js. I put the code like this

```
    listeners: {
       'click': function(){
          alert("hai");
          window.open('<%=request.getContextPath()%>/jsp/dashboard/helpwindow.jsp','_blank','toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=0,width=700,height=600');
       }
   }
```

But it does not give me the result. '<%=request.getContextPath()%>' makes problem.

Now th new window open with url

```
http://localhost:8080/hiring/%3C%=request.getContextPath%28%29%%3E/jsp/dashboard/helpwindow.jsp
```

But I need the url

```
http://localhost:8080/hiring/jsp/dashboard/helpwindow.jsp
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: It seems that your code between the <% and %> tag is not executed. Try to use white spaces and maybe use out.print: <% out.print(request.getContextPath()); %>

Comment: I tried this. but did not work. '<% out.print(request.getContextPath()); %>/jsp/dashboard/helpwindow.jsp'

Comment: It has nothing to do with Ext. The js file never gets interpreted by the server so the tags are meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
listeners: {

  'click': function() {                 
       var serverPath = window.location.href;
       var serverPathIndex = serverPath.lastIndexOf("/");
       window.open(serverPath.substring(0, serverPathIndex) + '/jsp/dashboard/helpwindow.jsp','_blank','toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=0,width=700,height=600');
   }
}
```